# Compile C++ Helloworld.cpp on VSCode and Mingw

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I am trying to compile and run a simple HelloWorld program via VSCode on Windows 10 but it fails to compile, even when following their [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

The only feedback I receive is:

```
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\g++.exe' -g c:\Users\admin\programming\helloworld.cpp -o c:\Users\admin\programming\helloworld.exe" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

I don't even receive any further information what exactly has failed. How can this can be fixed? Quite curiously, the same command

`& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\g++.exe' -g c:\Users\admin\programming\helloworld.cpp -o c:\Users\admin\programming\helloworld.exe`

performs perfectly well when I invoke it in a separate powershell.

C:\Users\admin\programming\Helloworld.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

C:\Users\admin\programming.vscode\tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

C:\Users\admin\programming.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "GCC",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Just curious, have you tried compiling with msbuild ?

Comment: @user3389943 No, and it's not installed. I just added that the compiler command works perfectly well in a separate powershell, so I believe it is not the compiler who's to blame.

Comment: Do you have the link to the tutorial you are following?

Comment: Is your mingw compatible with C++17? Probably the only thing I see is the C++17 specified in the cpp properties, which may or may not be the issue.

Comment: @user3389943: Has no effect

Comment: @alanboy: For your interest, I have added the link.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try returning zero in your program?

```
return 0;
```

Maybe the program is actually compiling and running but the non-zero return is interpreted as a failure.

Comment: `main` returns `0` by default, if control reaches `}`.

Comment: I did not downvote this, but there is no indication the code is ever executed. No executable is produced.